# Set text of cell if adjacent cell is between specified values

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am working on a student assessment sheet in Excel 2013. I want set the displayed text of a cell based on the value of another cell

e.g.

If the value of cell H3 is from 0 to 5, cell I3 should display "Beginner"
If the value of cell H3 is from 6 to 10, cell I3 should display "Pre-Intermediate"
If the value of cell H3 is from 11 to 15, cell I3 should display "Intermediate"
If the value of cell H3 is from 16 to 20, cell I3 should display "Advanced"

What is the best way to accomplish this? Can anyone suggest a formula I can use in Conditional Formatting to achieve this result?

Thank you

Comment: Focus more on the formula than conditional formatting.  Something like IF should get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell I3 put the formula (shortened the text for easy reading):

Solution 1:

```
=IF( H3<=5, "Beg", IF( H3<=10, "Pre", IF( H3<=15, "Int", "Adv" ) ) )
```

note: negative will be "Beginner", those over 15 will be "Advanced"

Solution 2:

```
=CHOOSE( RoundUp( H3/5, 0 ) + 1, "Beg", "Beg", "Pre", "Int", "Adv"))
```

note: values outside of 0-20 will be displayed as error, the first "Beg" is for the 0 value, 2nd "Beg" is for 1-5

Answer (score 1):

While there are multiple ways to do this in one formula only (see the other answers), I'd strongly recommend that you separate your "business logic", i.e. the levels ("beginner", ...) from the threshold values in a separate table - and then apply a simply `VLOOKUP` formula to it!

The advantage of this approach is, that you make the assumptions transparent to the user (or admin) and can later easily adjust them - without touching (or for the user even understanding) the formula!

To do so, place the small assumptions table somewhere in your workbook, say in sheet *Thresholds*, column A&B:

```
    A          B
    ___        _______________ 
1   Threshold  Level
2   0          Beginner
3   6          Pre-intermediate
4   11         Intermediate
5   16         Advanced
```

Now, you only need to place the following formula in the cell you want the level to appear:

```
=VLOOKUP(H3,Thresholds!$A:$B,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of values starts from A2, type in B2 the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),A2>=0,A2<=20),LOOKUP(A2,{0,6,11,16},{"Beginner","Pre-Intermediate","Intermediate","Advanced"}),"INCORRECT VALUE")
```

It will handle numbers outside the allowed range, as well as EMPTY cells or non-numeric data - `INCORRECT VALUE` will be displayed for these.

As for conditional formatting, you may easily apply coloring for all the grades as well as error returned. Good luck!

P.S. Sample file is shared: https://www.dropbox.com/s/or37zkabe7ictoh/GradesLookup.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$5, MATCH(H3,A$1:A$5))
```